# Is the enumeration of all paths between source and sink in a DAG NP-hard?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, np-complete

Given a directed acyclic graph (DAG), is there a known polynomial time algorithm for enumerating all paths between a source and a sink node?

I can understand that there may be exponential number of paths between the source and the sink, so a polytime algorithm for enumerating them is difficult.

In that case what is the proof that enumerating all paths between source and sink in a DAG is NP-hard?

Comment: An NP-complete problem must be a [decision problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decision_problem).  Enumerating all the paths in a directed graph is not a decision problem.

Comment: Agreed, but we can easily formulate this problem as deciding if there are `k` paths between source and sink to make it a decision problem.

Comment: We can't answer your question until you do just that, turn the function problem into a particular decision problem.

Comment: Done! Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 1):

The *number of paths* in a DAG may be exponential, but it can be *represented* in polynomial space.

In fact, it is easy to calculate: Just run through all of the vertices in topologically-sorted order and for each vertex compute how many paths *end* there. This is $1$ (for the single-vertex path) plus the sum of the number of paths that end at each of its predecessors. So counting them is in P.

If there are many different paths, you cannot hope to *enumerate* them all in polynomial time. You can enumerate them in linear *space* (just enumerate all subsets of vertices and check whether each of them form a path). Or you can number the paths sequentially and convert an arbitrary sequence number to a path in something like $O(n\log n)$ time.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this and I should rather change my question. Is the problem of enumerating all paths between source and sink NP-hard, and if so, what is the proof?

Comment: @Ain: "NP-hard" applies only to decision problems. You can't even ask that unless you change the question to be about some decision problem.

Comment: That is not true, I believe. Read definition here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness

Comment: @Ain: See the first three words in the "Definition" section of the article you link to.

Comment: And you can read the last sentence. "Another definition is to require that there is a polynomial-time reduction from an NP-complete problem G to H. As any problem L in NP reduces in polynomial time to G, L reduces in turn to H in polynomial time so this new definition implies the previous one. Awkwardly, it does not restrict the class NP-hard to decision problems, for instance it also includes search problems, or optimization problems."

Comment: @Ain: That does not make sense to me. In order to speak about (many-one) reductions _from_ a decision problem, the problem one reduces _to_ needs to be a decision problem too; otherwise what would it even mean for the reduction to be correct?

Comment: I feel you but ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Chapter 5 of Garey and Johnson perhaps gives the best account of the old-style definition of NP-hard.  An abridged version should be in Johnson's chapter of the Handbook of Theoretical Computer Science, but I haven't checked.  Knuth's early definition proposals are also found on the Web.  In sum, a search problem defines a binary relation on strings, each pair consisting of an instance and a solution.  It's easy to associate a string relation to a decision problem.  Finally, one replaces Karp reductions with Cook reductions (oracle machines).  Used to be well-known, but times have changed.